# AWS.HttpRequest error - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am using AWS.HttpRequest in lambda to make a call to an HTTPS endpoint, and I am getting this error:

```
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'
```

I can't find any information on what to do specific to HTTPS calls when using AWS.HttpRequest.

Basically, my code is like this (quite trivial):

```
    const req = new AWS.HttpRequest(url, region);
    req.method = 'POST';
    req.path = '/_bulk';
    req.body = doc;
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    req.headers.Host = endpoint.host;

    const send = new AWS.NodeHttpClient();
    send.handleRequest(req, null, (httpResp) => {
        let body = '';

        httpResp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
        });
        httpResp.on('end', () => {
            resolve({ response: httpResp, body });
        });
    }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
```

The code works fine if the endpoint is HTTP (same endpoint, just on port 80), but throws that error if I pass an HTTPS endpoint.

Update: I replaced AWS.HttpRequest with `https` node library and I get the same error. Looks like I'm missing something.

Comment: Hope you have confirmed that the endpoint has a valid certificate. There is no extra config required to make an https call.

Comment: Yes, it does have a valid certificate. Also, Google Chrome browser  would complain if the cert wasn't valid if I hit that endpoint in the browser, and it doesn't complain, loads the response just fine.

Comment: Does your endpoint uses client cert verification? Can you try to use https://google.com as an endpoint to make sure its not a library problem. If that goes well, there is something to do with the cert

Answer (score -2):

Please try with AWS congratulations as below

```
{
    Accesskey:your_access_key,
    Region: region_name,
    sslEnabled:false

}
```